# Unit test for Runnable

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have the following code:

```
public class TypesEngine
{
@VisibleForTesting
void types(@NonNull final FindTypes findTypes, @NonNull final List<String> types)
{
    final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(TYPES_NUMBER_OF_THREADS);

    for (final String type : types)
    {
        executorService.execute(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    findTypes.getRelatedInformation(type);
                }
                catch (final TypeNotFound e)
                {
                    log.info(String
                        .format(
                            "Caught TypeNotFound for type [%s].",
                            type));
                }
            }
        });
    }
    executorService.shutdown();
 }
}
```

I tried to the following unit test:

```
@Test
public void test_Types() throws Exception
{
    final List<String> types = Lists.newArrayList("type1","type2","type3");

    doAnswer(new Answer() {
        @Override
        public Object answer(final InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            throw new TypeNotFound();
        }
    }).when(findTypes).getRelatedInformation(anyString());

    typesEngine.types(findTypes, types);

    for(final String type : types)
    {
        verify(findTypes, times(1)).getRelatedInformation(type);
    }
}
```

But it always gives me the error that the verify method on is not being called. But if I add a system.out.println I can see that the different types are being called.

It would be great if anyone could tell me how to write the following unit test.

I'm using Mockito for my unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

You're verifying that `findTypes` has been called immediately after the tasks have been **submitted** to the executor. The executor hasn't had the time to execute its tasks yet.

Since you have no way with that design to block until the tasks have completed, you need to sleep long enough before verifying. A more reliable way of doing it would be to pass your executor service as argument, and call `awaitTermination()` to block until the executor is done, rather than sleeping.

Also, you can use `doThrow()` rather than `doAnswer()`

Comment: do I pass in the following to awaitTermination(): Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS?

Comment: I'm using .isTerminated tag to achieve the same purpose.

Comment: You pass a reasonable delay: if after that delay, the tasks have not completed yet, you can consider the test has failed.